# Android quantity strings - prevent Arabic numerals

Tags: android, localization, arabic

When the following quantity string is set into a `TextView`:

```
<plurals name="distance_mile">
    <item quantity="one">%d ميل</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d ميل</item>
</plurals>
```

it is rendered with **Arabic numbers**, e.g. 100 looks like ١٠٠.
Is there any way (other than replacing characters in the resulting string) to force **European numerals**? (like adding some **special unicode symbol** or something like that)

Thanks!

Comment: Arabic numerals are 0123..9, Hindi numerals are ٠١...

Comment: well, I see that they are called Hindu-Arabic (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0660/index.htm), not that it matters much

Comment: @alchemiss Did you find a solution?